# iOS UIButton scale animation

Tags: ios, uibutton, transformation, uianimation

i'm working on a UIButton animation where it moves along x-axis while it scales to its original size from the initial size. when i tried the code below it doesnt move to the point where it should go and doesn't scale up to its original size.

this is my code for initializing the button:

```
 _testBtn1.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
scaleBtn = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2);
[_testBtn1 setTransform: scaleBtn];
```

and this is my code for the moving/translation and scaling:

```
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50.0f, 0.0f);
CGAffineTransform animate = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleBtn, translate);
[_testBtn1 setTransform:animate];
```

any help, suggestion, advice will be appreciated. i'm new to iOS..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a custom type UIButton (either with IB by changing the type to Custom, or programmatically with

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];//set the button's image with 
[aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To move it, just animate its position normally...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{aButton.center = newCenter;}];
```

Or

```
CGRect originalFrame = aButton.frame;
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x, originalFrame.origin.y, originalFrame.size.width, 0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{aButton.frame = originalFrame;}];
```

OR Reffer this link
http://objectiveapple.blogspot.in/2011/10/23-quizapp-16-animate-scale-uibutton.html

Comment: i just get the moving/translation part using CGPoint and setCenter, now my problem will be the scaling part..it appears that when i use the CGAffineTransformMakeScale it affects the moving animation..

Comment: use this button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1,1.1); insted of CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: when im using this code:

' [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        _msgButton.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_msgButton.transform, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       //code
    }];'

the button moves to the lower left of button's frame while it shrinks..it looks like that its anchorPoint is the buttons lower left part..so, i tried setting its anchorPoint but still no effect

Comment: are you using custom button type ? [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; ?

Comment: im using storyboard and yes the uibutton is custom type,.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily done with Core Animation, take a look the the most basic one [CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple scale(bouncy) animation with completion handler implementation in swift.

Hope it'll help you or anyone else in some way.

`viewToanimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7,
                           delay: 0,
                           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
                           initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
                           animations: { _ in
                            viewToAnimate.transform = .identity
                },
                           completion: { _ in
                            //Implement your awesome logic here.
            })`

Answer (score 0):

I made this animation:

[image]

With this reusable class:

```
class AnimatedButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addTargets()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        addTargets()
    }
    
    func addTargets() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scaleDownAnimated), for: .touchDown)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scaleBackToNormalAnimated), for: [.touchUpOutside, .touchCancel, .touchUpInside])
    }
    
    @objc func scaleDownAnimated() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
        } completion: { _ in }
    }
    
    @objc func scaleBackToNormalAnimated() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        } completion: { _ in }
    }
}
```

Then just make the class of your button `AnimatedButton` like below (if you are using Storyboards) and use the button normally:

[image]